# How to send React.js files with express .senfFile?

Tags: html, reactjs, express

I am using create-react-app.

When you go to localhost:3001/test - it *does* serve up the HTML. But all you see is an empty page because nothing in the id "root" is rendered.

This is the code I have in my server:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})
```

and my HTML is close to this:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the few details provided, I'll give a checklist

**1- Make sure you have *root* in this part of your code**

```
ReactDOM.render(<YourApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**2- In your console, do you have any error messages similar to this?**

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

...Then your are just simply not receiving your data from the server because of CORS issues. Use this: [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

**3- Double check that your server that does the res.sendFile is running properly**, check your terminal to check for errors like "file not found" or similar issues.

**4- This works (I just tried it), try it in the same directory as your current server. Paste the code in testNode.js and run `node testNode.js` then visit http://localhost:3003/test**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3003

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

5- **Is the public/ folder readable? Does it have the right permissions? Try a `chmod -R 777 public/` (change it back later)**

Comment: When you tested this, did you only get the HTML back? Or did you have React rendering to the root div, and get the React.js to render also?

Because thank you for the answer. I did exactly this, but I am not getting the React to render. I am only getting the HTML. Which is great, but none of the React is showing up :(. I know I'm not having a CORS issue, console shows no errors and I have the ReactDOM.render. The public folder seems to be readable. Because I put an <h1> tag in the index.html. And I'm seeing the h1 tag render, but not the React.

Comment: This is just node without react.. it lets you try your server code first. Then when you are sure that the server returns what you need, you may move on debugging the client (react). I would need to see your react component to help you out...

Comment: Chances are that your issue is only related to document.getElementByID

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the location of the static files. For example if you use environment variable.

```
if(process.env.ENV === 'prod'){
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    const path = require('path');

    app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}
```

Also, do make sure to run `npm run build` in order to create all the necessary files for deployment.